# Issue with preventing duplicates in listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues preventing duplicates from being added to a listbox in Excel. I have two listboxes, lstBoxSurveyList and lstBoxSurveyRemove. I'm trying to add items from lstBoxSurveyList, but only if it's not already in lstBoxSurveyRemove. My code is below (just edited it). Any suggestions? I see some posts on VB.Net, but they don't seem to work in Excel.

```
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To lstBoxSurveyRemove.ListCount - 1
        If lstBoxSurveyRemove.List(i) = lstBoxSurveyList.Value Then
            MsgBox ("This value exists")
        Else
            lstBoxSurveyRemove.AddItem (lstBoxSurveyList.Value)
        End If

    Next i
```

Comment: You're looping over columns not rows

Comment: Thanks, just realized that and edited the code. It never gets inside the loop since the initial listcount of the box is 0.

Comment: You have to wait until you're done looping before you add the item, otherwise you're just checking the first item for a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until you're done looping before you add the item, otherwise you're just checking the first item for a match.

Something like this:

```
Dim i As Long, bFound As Boolean

For i = 0 To lstBoxSurveyRemove.ListCount - 1
    If lstBoxSurveyRemove.List(i) = lstBoxSurveyList.Value Then
        bFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
If Not bFound Then lstBoxSurveyRemove.AddItem lstBoxSurveyList.Value
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect. I understand now from seeing this that I was only looking at the first item.